# How can I find out a portable external hard disk's hardware details from within macOS?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mojave

I have two external hard disks attached at the moment.
[image]

Is it possible to find out, for example, the model number and serial number of these devices via command line?

I have already checked Disk Utility and it does not provide this information:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the following command.

```
system_profiler SPStorageDataType
```

You will have to parse the output. For example, I have a external HDD with a single volume named `RONSPASPORT`. The output relevant to this drive is given below.

```
RON2PASPORT:

  Available: 29.27 GB (29,266,157,568 bytes)
  Capacity: 500.11 GB (500,105,216,000 bytes)
  Mount Point: /Volumes/RON2PASPORT
  File System: Journaled HFS+
  Writable: Yes
  Ignore Ownership: Yes
  BSD Name: disk2s1
  Volume UUID: BD65890D-BBAB-357A-B073-6B24625466F5
  Physical Drive:
      Device Name: 5000BEV External
      Media Name: WD 5000BEV External Media
      Protocol: USB
      Internal: No
      Partition Map Type: MBR (Master Boot Record)
```

From the output, one can see this is a `WD 5000BEV`.

Also there is the command below.

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType
```

For the same external HDD, the following output is relevant.

```
        External HDD    :

          Product ID: 0x0705
          Vendor ID: 0x1058  (Western Digital Technologies, Inc.)
          Version: 1.75
          Serial Number: 57442D575836304139326384913837
          Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
          Manufacturer: Western Digital 
          Location ID: 0xfd130000 / 6
          Current Available (mA): 500
          Current Required (mA): 2
          Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
          Media:
            5000BEV External:
              Capacity: 500.11 GB (500,107,862,016 bytes)
              Removable Media: No
              BSD Name: disk2
              Logical Unit: 0
              Partition Map Type: MBR (Master Boot Record)
              USB Interface: 0
              Volumes:
                RON2PASPORT:
                  Capacity: 500.11 GB (500,105,217,024 bytes)
                  Available: 29.27 GB (29,266,153,472 bytes)
                  Writable: Yes
                  File System: Journaled HFS+
                  BSD Name: disk2s1
                  Mount Point: /Volumes/RON2PASPORT
                  Content: Apple_HFS
                  Volume UUID: BD65890D-BBAB-357A-B073-6B24625466F5
```

This provides more information, including the serial number.

> Note: The `system_profiler` command has the option `-detailLevel level` where the `level` can be `mini`, `basic` or `full`.

Comment: I am not sure why but I can't see any info regarding the make or the model. Not even the Manufacturer. The only bit I can see related to the device is: `Device Name: Elements 10B8`

Comment: You can not tell that make is Western Digital or that the model is a 5000BEV?

Comment: I am not talking about your output. My output is devoid of manufacturer related info for some reason.

Comment: I suppose the System Information application will not show anything either under Storage or USB in Hardware. Probably was nothing stored in the hardware to read. Note: You may need to select refresh from the menu bar to get a device to appear.

Comment: @AnthonyKong Your USB-enclosure may not pass this information through.